# kill an app by name and time

Tags: macos, command-line

is there a Terminal command to kill an app by name at a certain time?
have an app that the dev seems to be a little behind on and it intermittently won't get my scheduled shutdown occur.

Comment: I don't think there's a time option for any built-in command; though you could of course schedule the command to run. Is your scheduled shutdown scripted? Why isn't the app quitting at shutdown? What do you shut down for?

Comment: the shutdown is part of the Energy sys pref.  
The app seems to think it needs to do a firmware update, which I have confirmed it does not and certainly not every other night.
I don't like leaving electronics on all night if there is no need.
Which is the exact opposite of my work in recording studios.
Everything stays on 24/7.

Comment: Applications can‘t do firmware updates on Mac hardware, which specific application is this?

Comment: not Mac hardware. ext audio I/O

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pkill` (which allows to terminate processes by name) and `cron` (scheduling) for this.

First, let's find the actual name of the application you want to terminate.

1. Open Activity Monitor
2. Select the application you want to terminate ("UAD Meter & Control Panel", I assume)
3. Type <kbd>Cmd-I</kbd> to open the info window
4. Select the 3rd tab ("Open Files and Ports")
5. Note down the part after the last `/` of the second line shown. In my example below, it would be `Skim` (case matters)

[image]

Now, let's create an entry for the `cron` scheduler, to be run at 17:30 each day.

1. Open Terminal
2. Run `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`
3. This puts you into an text editor within Terminal, add the following line there (replace NAME with the name you noted down in step 5 above)

```
30 17 * * * pkill 'NAME'; sleep 5; pkill -9 'NAME'
```

4. Type <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> to exit, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the file name and answer the save prompts.
5. Close Terminal

Comment: K.  I guess there is no way to email subscribe to threads?  Seems odd.  But I'll get back in a few days either way.

Comment: @Fritz You can follow a question (link at the bottom of it) to be notified of changes. And AFAIK you can set email notifications in your profile.

Comment: been 5 days without the issue popping up, so I'm thinking it's cured.
Thanks nohillside.  Onto my next conundrum.